# http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I have this problem when execute apt-get update in ubuntu 14.04

`W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_main_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch`

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Edit sources.list and comment out:

```
#deb-src http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
```

than

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```